# making cookie name configurable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-cookies

I am using angular ngCookies to read cookies.
At present I am using this line to read cookie

```
$cookies.MYCOOKIE
```

The problem is that here I have to hard code cookie name, I have different cookie name in test/prod environment, but not able to find a way to read cookie  from a variable.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript everything is object and to access object property, you should use  for example `$cookies[variable_name]`.